# Modify the current email body outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to replace in the active email the "text1" with "text2" . Here is my code:

```
Sub Custmod()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim olOutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sText As String
Dim vText As String
Dim strBody As String
Set objOL = Application
Set objItem = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    For i = 1 To UBound(vText)
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "TEXT1") Then
            olItem.body = Replace(vText(i), "TEXT2", "")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What doesn't work?

Comment: UBound expects array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use an array when not needed.

Replace works on multiple instances of the same word.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Custmod()

Dim olItem As mailItem

Set olItem = CreateItem(olMailItem)
olItem.body = "TEXT1" & Chr(13) & "Here is some stuff." & Chr(13) & "TEXT1 again."
olItem.Display
MsgBox olItem.body

olItem.body = Replace(olItem.body, "TEXT1", "TEXT2")
MsgBox olItem.body

Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```